# SQL multiple-value parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is what I have:

```
 select *
 from AuditQuestionnaires
 where Companyid = @companyid 
   and RiskTypeID != @RiskIdList[x];
```

Why can't I add a parameter like this:

```
command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RiskIdList[x]", RiskIdList[x]));
```

I'm using SQL Server, and this is the script I'm using in .cs file

Comment: First of all, this would not be valid SQL. In SQL you cannot use `!=` on data sets, but only on single values. So what you are looking for is rather `risktypeid NOT IN (...)`. Unfortunately though, data sets cannot be used as bind variables, as far as I know. This may be different for DBMS that support arrays like PostgreSQL does. What is the DBMS you are asking this for?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter: I made an educated guess and have updated the request accordingly :-)

Comment: You can however, with a few tweaks, use a tabled valued parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since you are using SQL Server, you cannot have a parameter named @RiskTypeId[x].  It is simply not a valid name.

Secondly, when passsing parameters from c# the parameter name has to include the initial "@".

Thirdly, as a general rule it is much better to construct the SQLParameter including the DataType.  This means that there is no guesswork required, and guesses occasionally go wrong.

Fourthly, it seems to me that you want to iterate through an array. There is nothing to stop you doing this in c#.  You would simply create a SqlParameter like this

```
command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@RiskTypeId", DBType = DBType.Int32, Value = RiskIDList[x] });
```

However I suspect that what you are really trying to do is to send a list to SQL Server.  To achieve this, you need to use a `User-Defined Table Type`.  In your case the following is sufficient:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE ([Id] int);
```

Then you can define a parameter to your query as:

```
@RiskTypeIdList IdList READONLY
```

Finally you have to put the contents of your array into a DataTable.  Because this is something I do frequently, I have a Class for this job:

```
public class TDataTable<int> : DataTable
{
    public TDataTable(IEnumerable<T> ids) : base()
    {
        Columns.Add("Id", typeof(T));
        var added = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach (T id in ids)
        {
            //ensure unique values
            if (added.Add(id))
            {
                Rows.Add(id);
            }
        }
    }
    public TDataTable() : base()
    {
        Columns.Add("Id", typeof(T));
    }
}
```

You can then pass the parameter like this:

```
command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@RiskTypeIdList", SqlDBType = SqlDBType.Structured, Value = new TDataTable<int>(RiskIDList) });
```

Within your SQL you can then do what Thorsten suggested:

```
WHERE RiskTypeId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @RiskTypeIdList)
```

Comment: Tip: [HashSet.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add) returns `false` if the element was already present - so you can replace the "Contains" check

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks for the tip!  I have changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

@Thorsten Kettner, its a valid SQL query, we can != in sql query.

```
command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RiskIdList[x]", RiskIdList[x]));
```

We cannot pass "RiskIdList[x]" as SQL Parameter, we need to pass parameter like this "RiskIdList", RiskIdList[x] means that you are passing argument at runtime, but query or stored procedure has not dynamic parameter in where clause.

Comment: so i have list of values in RiskIdlist so how I give a specific value to this statement ( my purpose of feed with all values in the list to SQL  statement )

Comment: we can pass table parameter to SQL server. From C#, we can send DataTable and in SQL , we can use Table-Value parameter as CREATE TYPE LessonType AS TABLE
(RiskId   INT).  For more detail about Table- Value parameter, please visit https://www.sqlshack.com/table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server/